# No consigo matricular alumnos manualmente con un Script en Moodle

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

Estoy intentando matricular alumnos manualmente en un curso de `Moodle` mediante un `Script` pero no lo consigo. Estoy utilizando la función `role_assign` de `Moodle` pero no me funciona.

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
//obtiene el id del rol "member" que ha sido creado anteriormente
$rolMember = obtenerIdRol ("member");
$rolManager = obtenerIdRol ("manager" );

$contexto = context_course::instance($comunidad_moodle);

foreach ($usuariosUVDotlrn as $usu) {   
    $userid = null;
    $usernameDotln = $usu["username"];
    $rolDotln = $usu["rol"];

    if($rolDotln == "dotlrn_admin_rel"){
        $rolid = $rolManager;
    }else if($rolDotln == "dotlrn_member_rel"){
        $rolid = $rolMember;
    }else{
        $rolid = -1;
    }

    //obtenemos el id del usuario en Moodle
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM mdl_user WHERE username = ?";
    $resUsu = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($usernameDotln));

    foreach ( $resUsu as $n ) {                         
        $userid = $n->id;
    }                           

    //Comprobamos que el usuario existe en moodle.
    if( is_null($userid)){
        m("- El usuario: $usernameDotln no existe en la Base de Datos de Moodle");

    }else{                                                                                      
        //Comprobamos si el usuario pertenece al curso
        $enrolled = is_enrolled($contexto, $userid, '', true);

        if( !$enrolled){                                                
            if($rolid != -1){                                                                                               
                $idroleassign = role_assign($rolid , $userid, $contexto);

                m("- El usuario: $usernameDotln con id: $userid y rol: $rolid insertado en el curso: $comunidad_moodle");
            }else{                                                  
                m("- El usuario: $usernameDotln con id: $userid y rol: $rolid no esta en el curso: $comunidad_moodle. No se ha encontrado el rol.");
            }                                               
        }else{                              
            m("- El usuario: $usernameDotln con id: $userid ya pertenece al curso: $comunidad_moodle");
        }
    }                               
}
```

Nota: la funcion m("") se encarga de mostrar el texto en la consola

Nota2: la función `obtenerIdRol` es la siguiente:

```
/**
 * Devuelve el id del rol pasado.
 *
 * @param $rol nombre del rol.
 *
 * @return id del rol 
 */
function obtenerIdRol ($rol ){

    global $DB;
    $id = null;

    //obtenemos el id del rol en Moodle
    $sqlrol = "SELECT id FROM mdl_role WHERE shortname = ?";
    $roles = $DB->get_records_sql($sqlrol, array($rol));

    foreach ( $roles as $r ) {                      
        $id = $r->id;
    }

    if(is_null($id))
        return -1;
    else
        return $id;
}
```

Si alguien conoce cómo hacerlo o tiene algún ejemplo o documentación que me pueda servir, será una gran ayuda para mi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de buscar y probar algunas cosas, he encontrado una solución que funciona, y consiste en instanciar el plugin de enrol con tipo manual para que la asignación de los alumnos se haga a través del plugin.

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
//obtiene el id del rol "member" que ha sido creado anteriormente
$rolMember = obtenerIdRol ("member");
$rolManager = obtenerIdRol ("manager" );

$contexto = context_course::instance($comunidad_moodle);

// Recuperamos el plugin de enrol manual.
$enrol = enrol_get_plugin('manual');

// Comprobar si la instancia del plugin de enrolment manual está habilitada/existe.
$instance = null;
$enrolinstances = enrol_get_instances($comunidad_moodle, true);
foreach ($enrolinstances as $courseenrolinstance) {
    if ($courseenrolinstance->enrol == "manual") {
        $instance = $courseenrolinstance;
        break;
    }
}

if (!empty($instance)) {

    foreach ($usuariosUVDotlrn as $usu) {   
         $userid = null;
         $usernameDotln = $usu["username"];
         $rolDotln = $usu["rol"];

         if($rolDotln == "dotlrn_admin_rel"){
              $rolid = $rolManager;
         }else if($rolDotln == "dotlrn_member_rel"){
              $rolid = $rolMember;
         }else{
              $rolid = -1;
         }

         //obtenemos el id del usuario en Moodle
         $sql = "SELECT id FROM mdl_user WHERE username = ?";
         $resUsu = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($usernameDotln));

         foreach ( $resUsu as $n ) {                         
               $userid = $n->id;
         }                           

         //Comprobamos que el usuario existe en moodle.
         if( is_null($userid)){
               m("- El usuario: $usernameDotln no existe en la Base de Datos de Moodle");

         }else{                                                                                      
              //Comprobamos si el usuario pertenece al curso
              $enrolled = is_enrolled($contexto, $userid, '', true);

              if( !$enrolled){                                                
                   if($rolid != -1){ 
                        $enrol->enrol_user($instance, $userid, $rolid, time(), 0, ENROL_USER_ACTIVE);
                        m("- El usuario: $usernameDotln con id: $userid y rol: $rolid insertado en el curso: $comunidad_moodle");
                   }else{                                                  
                        m("- El usuario: $usernameDotln con id: $userid y rol: $rolid no esta en el curso: $comunidad_moodle. No se ha encontrado el rol.");
                   }                                               
              }else{                              
                   m("- El usuario: $usernameDotln con id: $userid ya pertenece al curso: $comunidad_moodle");
              }
         } 
     }                              
}
```

Comment: me parece perfecto que compartas la respuesta :D Creo que se necesitan 2 días para aceptar tu propia respuesta, recuerda hacerlo para colaborar con la salud del sitio :D Saludos y que sigan los éxitos con el moodle!

Comment: Muchas gracias!! espero que le sirva mi respuesta a más gente!

Answer (score 1):

En mi desconocimiento tanto de Moodle como de PHP di con esta forma de matricular a un alumno en un curso. La comparto porque me parece un poco más sencilla que la respuesta aceptada.

**UPDATE**: En la plataforma para la que trabajo me han pedido que los alumnos sólo tengan 60 días para completar los cursos, así que hay que especificar el tiempo de matriculación al registrarlos. Lo añado al código, al final.

```
//Partimos de que existen las variables $userid, $courseid y $roleid
//$roleid en este caso es 'student'. Se puede consultar en la tabla <prefijo>_role
global $DB;

$user = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => $userid, 'deleted' => 0), '*', MUST_EXIST);
$course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $courseid), '*', MUST_EXIST);

$context = context_course::instance($course->id);

if (!is_enrolled($context, $user)) {
    echo "<br> Usuario NO REGISTRADO";
    $enrol = enrol_get_plugin("manual");
    if ($enrol === null) {
        return false;
    }
    $instances = enrol_get_instances($course->id, true);
    $manualinstance = null;
    foreach ($instances as $instance) {
        if ($instance->name == $enrolmethod) {
            $manualinstance = $instance;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($manualinstance !== null) {
        $instanceid = $enrol->add_default_instance($course);
        if ($instanceid === null) {
            $instanceid = $enrol->add_instance($course);
        }

        $instance = $DB->get_record('enrol', array('id' => $instanceid));
    }

    //Tiempo en formato epoch: segundos desde 1970.
    $enrolstart = time();
    $enrolperiod = 60; //60 dias de duracion de la matricula
    // Multiplicamos los dias de vigencia por el número de segundos que hay en 1 dia=60*60*24
    $enrolend = $enrolstart + ($enrolperiod*86400);
    $enrol->enrol_user($instance, $userid, $roleid, $enrolstart, $enrolend);
    //el periodo de matriculacion es opcional, si no se quiere usar cambiar la anterior linea por la siguiente
    //$enrol->enrol_user($instance, $userid, $roleid);

}
else {
    echo "<br> Usuario registrado";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación! En su momento no di con otra forma de hacerlo, pero siempre es bueno saber más de una forma de como hacer las cosas. Gran aporte!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $functionname = 'enrol_manual_enrol_users';
    $matricula= new stdClass();
    $matricula->roleid =5; ////estudante -> 5
    $matricula->userid  = 75471;
    $matricula->courseid = 1160;
    $params = array($matricula); 

    $serverurl = 'http://moodle.edu.pe/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl=1&wstoken=423423432dfsdfsdfsds';

    $client = new SoapClient($serverurl);

    try {
        $resp = $client->__soapCall($functionname, array($params));
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        exit($e->faultstring);
    }
?>
```